# ImageView inside ListView is ignoring all layout dimensions and filling the whole screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to create a set of 4 dynamically updating listviews of icons.
To do this, I've put my 4 listviews inside a gridview, and I'm using a custom layout for each listview item with a single imageview inside it. I'm handling changing the icon inside a custom adapter. I'm using the Picasso library to handle the icons, and all my icons are stored locally in drawable as .png files.

I'm not getting any errors, but when I run the app, all I get is a single icon that takes up the whole screen. I have a small imageview and a textview above the gridview that contains the lists of icons, but the one icon pushes even that out of the way.

This is my layout preview, and a screenshot of the app running in an emulator. (the result is the same if I run on my phone).

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9LxT.jpg),
[running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40N9S.jpg)

(apologies for not embedding, I'm new to SO, and don't have 10 rep yet haha)

I've tried resizing the image at runtime inside my custom adapter. I've tried setting the maximum width of the listview - both at runtime (since I want to adapt to different screen dimensions), and in the xml files. I've tried resizing the source .png files outside of android studio. Nothing's worked.

My activity xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sta.tomov0.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tomoFace"
        android:src="@drawable/office38"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tomoFace"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:columnCount="5">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewA"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewB"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewC"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewD"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="addTask"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more" />

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My listview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my activity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView tomoface;
    ListView listViewA;
    ArrayList arrayListA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Boolean aExists = false;
    ListView listViewB;
    ArrayList arrayListB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Boolean bExists = false;
    ListView listViewC;
    ArrayList arrayListC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Boolean cExists = false;
    ListView listViewD;
    ArrayList arrayListD = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Boolean dExists = false;
    Button addButton;
    TextView tomoText;
    File tomoFiles;
    File taskFiles;
    String currentCommunity = "Dep";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Paper.init(getApplicationContext());

        tomoface = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tomoFace);
        tomoface.setImageResource(R.drawable.favourite15);
        tomoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listViewA = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewA);
        listViewB = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewB);
        listViewC = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewC);
        listViewD = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewD);
        tomoFiles = getDir("TomoFiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
        taskFiles = new File(tomoFiles, "taskFiles");

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width =(size.x)/5;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listViewA.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = width;
        params.width = width;

        listViewA.setLayoutParams(params);
        listViewB.setLayoutParams(params);
        listViewC.setLayoutParams(params);
        listViewD.setLayoutParams(params);

        /*
        If there is no data saved, the following code creates a list of (empty) lists to hold TaskClass objects
        The 4 sub lists each represent one category.
        If there is data saved, the following code retrieves that data, and creates 4 new ArrayLists,
        each containing the iconIds of the TaskClass objects in the corresponding position of the corresponding TaskClass arraylist.
        These ArrayLists of ids are then used to populate the 4 listviews.
        */
        ArrayList<ArrayList<TaskClass>> listList = Paper.book(currentCommunity).read("listList", new ArrayList<ArrayList<TaskClass>>());
        if (listList.size() == 0){
            listList.add(new ArrayList<TaskClass>());
            listList.add(new ArrayList<TaskClass>());
            listList.add(new ArrayList<TaskClass>());
            listList.add(new ArrayList<TaskClass>());
        } else {

            for(TaskClass t:listList.get(0)){
                arrayListA.add(t.getIcon());
            }

            for(TaskClass t:listList.get(1)){
                arrayListB.add(t.getIcon());
            }

            for(TaskClass t:listList.get(2)){
                arrayListC.add(t.getIcon());
            }

            for(TaskClass t:listList.get(3)){
                arrayListD.add(t.getIcon());
            }
        }

        Integer[] intArrayA = new Integer[arrayListA.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListA.size(); i++){
            intArrayA[i] =(Integer) arrayListA.get(i);

        }
        ArrayAdapter adapterA = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),intArrayA);
        listViewA.setAdapter(adapterA);

        Integer[] intArrayB = new Integer[arrayListB.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListB.size(); i++){
            intArrayB[i] =(Integer) arrayListB.get(i);

        }
        ArrayAdapter adapterB = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),intArrayB);
        listViewB.setAdapter(adapterB);

        Integer[] intArrayC = new Integer[arrayListC.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListC.size(); i++){
            intArrayC[i] =(Integer) arrayListC.get(i);

        }
        ArrayAdapter adapterC = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),intArrayC);
        listViewC.setAdapter(adapterC);

        Integer[] intArrayD = new Integer[arrayListD.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListD.size(); i++){
            intArrayD[i] =(Integer) arrayListD.get(i);

        }
        ArrayAdapter adapterD = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),intArrayD);
        listViewD.setAdapter(adapterD);



    }

    //TODO: create a custom adapter that will display icons correctly
    public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
        private final Context context;
        private final Integer[] values;

        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, Integer[] values) {
            super(context, -1, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View iconView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.iconlayout, parent, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) iconView.findViewById(R.id.listImageView);

            int s =(int) values[position];
            imageView.setImageResource(s);


            //get the device width, to calculate icon width, and then set icon width accordingly
            //TODO: setting icon width not working
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width =(size.x)/5;

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.sta.tomov0/drawable/"+s);
            Picasso.with(context).load(uri).resize(width,width).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);


            return iconView;
        }

    }
}
```

A note: I have a custom data management class that returns arraylists. That's tested separately and working fine. The arraylists that are being fed to the adapter are int arraylists of the drawable references.

Help! What am I doing wrong? I've been searching through SO all day and trying different things. The solutions posted in these questions haven't helped T-T:
[How to set ImageView width in android ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631750/how-to-set-imageview-width-in-android-listview)
[ImageView in ListView that expands maximum width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287197/imageview-in-listview-that-expands-maximum-width)
(that was a bit difficult to implement, and just created other problems - it seems like overkill to create a custom view class just for displaying an icon?)

Comment: what are the dimensions of you icon image?

Comment: the dimensions of the file are 512x512, but I tried with a resized one (I scaled it 50% in paint, and then added it back into android studio) and had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Give fixed height to your Imageview in My listview layout:
Say Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/listImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't fix the problem :/
Also, it doesn't allow me to dynamically set image size according to screen width, which is what I'd ideally like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `@drawable/office38` is the image shown in your screenshot (taking up the whole screen)?

Try setting the dimensions of this image to something small, eg:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

I know this may not be what you are actually looking to do, but at least it will show you if the problem is with that first ImageView or not and will free up space below it for the TextView and the GridLayout. It could be that the drawable is massive, and as you aren't specifying a set width/height or any scale options, it takes up all the space it can.

Also, have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType which describes the different scaling options you have with an ImageView.

Comment: it's actually @drawable/favourite15 - it's an icon I got off flaticon.com. The icon is set in TaskClass though (printing to logs confirms that it's coming out of that correctly).
I've tried setting the dimensions to something small, but it's not having any effect. also, I'd ideally like to scale the actual png, rather than the imageview, to conserve memory.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT.
sorry guys. It was a really dumb problem after all.

My listview adapter is working fine it turns out. The problem was in the imageview that was *outside* of the lists (tomoface) - for some reason, I decided to set it to a different drawable on runtime, and hadn't scaled that at all haha.